# ObjC - Resizing and Getting Window Dimensions

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, window, window-resize

In objective C, I'm trying to resize an application window after a button is clicked. If the window was 200x200, a (+) button is pressed to make it 200x210 or the (-) button is pressed to make it 200x190.

I'm just not sure how to set the size of windows after they're made in the editor.

Don't have sample code because it's simple and I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
- (IBAction)plusButtonClicked:(NSControl *)sender
{
  NSRect frame = sender.window.frame;

  frame.size.height += 20;

  [sender.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
}
```

Depending whether you want the top or bottom of the window to expand, you may also need:

```
frame.origin.y -= 20;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That was perfect. But also, how can I send this to the window when the application initializes, like call this in the app delegate?

Comment: Depending on how your xib files are structured, it might be difficult to use your app delegate. You will generally want a controller object of some kind in the same xib as the window, and then have an outlet connecting them, and it does the resize in awakeFromNib. If you are trying to remember the window size across app launches, NSWindow has an autosave facility, you should be able to just type an autosave identifier into the window in interface builder, and it will remember the previous size/position.

Comment: One more thing Abhi, I posted another question on this, but I was using another thing to resize the window except it was adjusting the window to a set height and not adding to the current height. Problem is, the items inside the window are disappearing, I'm thinking it has to do with the origin.y is off... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920025/obj-c-resizing-window-removes-window-items

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at setFrame:display: in the NSWindow Class Reference.

Comment: Can I not use an IBOutlet NSWindow* and then setFrame to that window? With the NSWindow* connected to the window interface builder.

Comment: Yes, that's how you would do it -- you need some reference to your window, and the IBOutlet is that reference. You can also use the NSApplication method mainWindow to get the main window of an application.