# Obj C - Resizing Window Removes Window Items

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, window, window-resize

When I try to resize a window after a button is pressed, everything inside the window disappears and I believe it has to do with the origin of the window.

```
    NSRect frame = sender.window.frame;    
float d; //how much the window is changing
NSLog(@"the frame origin of y = %f", frame.origin.y);
d = (frame.size.height - 115);
NSLog(@"d variable = %f.", d);
frame.origin.y += d;
NSLog(@"the frame origin of y = %f", frame.origin.y);
frame.size.height = 115;
[sender.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
```

The window is supposed to change its height to 115 and to ensure the top bar stays in the same place, the origin.y is adjusted however much the height had to change, yet when I test this, the top bar stays in the same place, but all the items inside the window disappear.

Comment: I think it's more likely that it has to do with autosizing. Where things go when the window shrinks will depend on how the struts are set up.  What do you want to happen?  Some things will have to disappear if your window gets too small.  Do they really disappear? If you make the window bigger do they come back?

Comment: If I run the app with the window already at the smaller size, the items fit. However, If I run that code snippet and, as you said, try to make it big again only a few things reappear. If I setHidden to some items before it gets smaller I can make them reappear. But If I try to make them appear again if I didn't hide them before the window gets smaller, they will not come back. Sorry... confusing...